# How to Convert all Absolute path to relative path in flutter import?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert all absolute paths to relative paths in flutter without doing one by one. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Can you please add more details and maybe an example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I am answering my own question. I found an awesome vs code extension called [dart-import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=luanpotter.dart-import).

After installing this extension. you just need to open command pallet using `ctrl+shift+P` and search for `fix all import` and `Enter`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool available for that from Dart v2.12:

https://dart.dev/tools/dart-fix

In short:

First run with `dart fix --dry-run` to see what's going to change.

If satisfied with results, run `dart fix --apply` to apply all the changes seen in the dry run.